# how to set env in Sheel for node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment-variables

```
shell:$ set CONF = 44
```

`const mytext = process.env.CONF console.log(mytext);`

//undefined

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Powershell,

```
$Env:CONF = 'Hello, World!'
```